# macOS Ventura: Is there a keyboard shortcut for cycling through stage manager groups?

Tags: macos, mac, macos-ventura

Stage Manager seems like it could be really powerful and helpful, but without keyboard shortcuts to cycle through groups it means I have to put my hand on the mouse and click. Who has time for that? I found a shortcut for turning it on and off, buuuuut...

Are there any shortcuts for Stage Manager to cycle through groups?

Comment: MacOS Ventura 13.1 does NOT provide any keyboard shortcuts for stage manager operations including cycling through stage manager groups

Answer (score 1):

1. It is possible to cycle through the applications of the active group of the stage manager. This is `<CMD>+<Backtick>`, the same as cycling the windows of one application if the stage manager is off.

   For me, this is the most powerful feature of the stage manager. So far this shortcut could cycle through the windows of one application. Now it can cycle through the windows of different applications that are grouped by one concern.

   My typical use case is to group multiple applications of a single concern. I may have three concerns in parallel, coding a program, writing a blog and learning a new topic. So far I would separate the concerns onto three different desktops aka workspaces aka spaces but I didn't have a feature to cycle through each workspace. This is now possible by groupings a workspace into one group of the stage manager.
2. Following this setup I can also cycle between the different groups of the stage manager, by assigning one workspace into one group. I just use the shortcuts to cycle the workspaces, `<CTRL`> plus the arrow keys.

Discussion

The question is a little ambiguous. What means cycling "through" groups? It is rather between groups or inside groups? I tried to answer both as both are needed to navigate by keyboard.

While the first part is a direct answer to the question, the second part is a workaround. It works for a form of organisation of the applications that I address as concern orientated. It still doesn't work well.

If I could cycle through all windows of one workspace I would not need the stage manager. Improving the workspace would have been the better choice for me. Apple addresses the same challenge with two different solutions that only give a partly answer each. The need to combine both makes it overly complicated. Yet I get close to a concern orientated approach that I am looking for since two decades.

Comment: Sadly a bit unfulfilling to me. I want to use only one Desktop and wish to walk-through the states with via keyboard navigation. This is no solution for me, but good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that there is an option to set a shortcut key to toggle stage manager off and on.

It’s in:

Mac settings,
keyboard section,
Keyboard Shortcuts
Mission Control
I set mine to F3 which - on my keyboard - is the same key you press to get mission control, but with the function key held down - (which makes it easier for me to remember).

Hope this helps - I was under the impression this wasn’t possible.

https://talk.macpowerusers.com/t/shortcut-key-to-toggle-stage-manager-off-and-on-who-knew/34576

Comment: Sorry, it does not help. The question is about navigating through the spaces of the Stage Manager, not about having a hot key to turn it on or off.